# ActionBar's Navigation Mode Changes during ConfigChanges

Tags: java, android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I am using actionbarsherlock's ActionBar, the first time you run the application in landscape or horizontal orientation the tabs is displayed in `Tabs Mode`. After changing the orientation to portrait the nav mode is still in `Tabs`. The second time changing the orientation to `horizontal` the tabs are displayed as a `List` and only the parent item is displayed and the rest are hidden. I heard that this is a bug to Android, the system automatically changes the nav mode to `list` if the tabs are too many to fit the screen. But the thing is the first time I load the application is it displayed as `tabs` mode even horizontally. By the way I created **100 tabs**.

*This image is in horizontal view. The first image from the top is just the result after I change the phone's orientation to portrait then go back to landscape.*
[image]

---

I have this code from my **Manifest File**,

`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

**Main Activity**

```
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
         ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
             ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

             if(ab.getNavigationMode() != ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS){
                 ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

             }
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Just to make sure I also put the code, somewhere near the `setContentView`

```
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

**UPDATE:**

The reason why I am handling the `onConfigurationChanged` because I got a **Null Pointer Exception**.

**Logcat**

```
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.actionbarsherlock.sample.styled/com.actionbarsherlock.sample.styled.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3512)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.nineoldandroids.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.setupSetterAndGetter(PropertyValuesHolder.java:504)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator.initAnimation(ObjectAnimator.java:410)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:538)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:928)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:951)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:385)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.actionbarsherlock.sample.styled.MainActivity.rotateLeftFrag(MainActivity.java:218)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.actionbarsherlock.sample.styled.MainActivity.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:256)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarWrapper$TabWrapper.onTabSelected(ActionBarWrapper.java:356)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:570)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.setSelectedNavigationItem(ActionBarImpl.java:356)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.setNavigationMode(ActionBarImpl.java:1158)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarWrapper.setNavigationMode(ActionBarWrapper.java:216)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.actionbarsherlock.sample.styled.MainActivity.showTabsNav(MainActivity.java:244)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at com.actionbarsherlock.sample.styled.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-05 15:36:18.486: E/AndroidRuntime(30044):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: you want tabs in List as like your first image or in Tab as like your second image ?

Comment: I'd like the second image, that is before I change orientation. The first image is the result.

Comment: What happens if you don't handle the orientation change ?

Comment: got null pointer exception, so I handled the orientation and screen change.

Comment: null pointer you can easily handle, just see the flow of code and check where you are initializing the object.

Comment: Thanks for giving me options @PiyushMishra. By the way I added a logcat error maybe you have an idea on it. I can't understand the error this time

Comment: just double click on the error and it will lead you the the source line, where you are getting this error. put a log before that to see which object is null, may be in your animation folder inside PropertyValuesHolder class just check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a default behavior of the tabs in android. If there is no more space for tabs in horizontal/portrait orientation then it will converted to list.

Now, if you still want to have all the tabs not in list then what i suggest is to look at this sample of [ViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/SampleTabsDefault.java) after that you should have to add that FragmentActivity in to your SherlockFragmentActivity. Just check below Example Code what i am doing which will help you to have all tabs with any orientation.

```
public class TestSampleTabDefault extends SherlockActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static class SampleTabsDefault extends FragmentActivity implements ServiceConnection {
        private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Albums", "Artists", "Songs", "Playlist","Genre","Recently Played","Easy Transfer" };
        Handler mHandler;
        //Runnable mRunnable;
        private ServiceToken mToken;
        private IRemoteService  mIRemoteService;
        public static ViewPager pager;
        public static int index = 0;
        public static android.app.ActionBar mActionBar;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);

            //getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            //ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
            //bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            //bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

            FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new GoogleMusicAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);

            /*getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);*/

            TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
            indicator.setViewPager(pager);

            index = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("index");
            if(index >0){
                indicator.setCurrentItem(index);
            }

        }

        class GoogleMusicAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
             private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
             private Fragment mFragmentAtPos0;
            public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
                mFragmentManager = fm;
            }
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
               // return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
                Fragment fm = null;

                if(position==0){// LOAD ALBUMS
                    fm = ArtistList.ArtistListFragment.newInstance();
                    return fm;

                }else if(position==1){// LOAD ARTISTS
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select Album", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fm = ArtistList.ArtistListFragment.newInstance();
                    return fm;
                }else if(position==2){// LOAD SONGS
                    fm = SongsList.SongsListFragment.newInstance(); 
                    return fm;
                }else if(position==3){   // PLaylist
                    fm = PlaylistList.PlayListFragment.newInstance();
                    return fm;
                }else if(position==4){ // Genre List
                    fm = GenreList.GenreListFragment.newInstance();
                    return fm;
                }else if(position==5){ // Recent List
                    fm = RecentAddedList.RecentListFragment.newInstance();
                    return fm;
                }else{
                    fm = TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position]);
                }
                return fm;


            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
              return CONTENT.length;
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemPosition(Object object)
            {
                if (object instanceof AlbumListFragment && mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof TestFragment)
                    return POSITION_NONE;
                return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Hope this will help you. All The Best. Let me know if you get any difficulty in that.

Comment: I have used to example before, let me try. Thanks!